What rotary changeover switch do I need to be able to run 2 different well pumps?
I have 2 pumps that I am in need of installing power. I have 12/3 wire to the box but don't know what switch I need and how to wire it in. My pumps won't ever be ran simultaneously so a changeover switch is best. The pumps are 220V at like 6-7 amps. What switch should I get and how do I wire this switch to transfer from one pump to the other. I would also like to have an OFF position so a 3 position switch would be best.

How many HP are these pumps? You can get normal snap switches in on-off and 3-way that are horsepower rated, and if your pumps are small enough loads that could be a super easy option.

The one pump is 1 hp. The other will most likely be 1/2-3/4 hp

You need a double-pole, double-throw, center off switch.
The good news is that at < 10A they are not that hard to find. People look for 30A versions for dryer + EV or 50A for welder + EV and it gets complicated and/or expensive.
For example, the Leviton 1286-W:

currently around $60 from Home Depot (may be more or less at other places and will change over time) will do the job quite well. Rated for 20A but 16A for motor but that's double what you said you need so it's good.
As far as wiring, pumps generally don't need neutral. But each pump needs both hots. So 12/3 probably is not really needed - i.e., you need 12/2 everywhere - but if it is already paid for then you just cap off the white (neutral) wire.

12/2 from breaker to switch
12/2 from switch to pump 1
12/2 from switch to pump 2


https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0D2B4LLH8?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

THis is kind of what I'm looking for. Would this one work?

NO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 1 - It is single-pole, you need double-pole; 2 - It has absolutely no indication of UL, ETL or similar listing (even as a component). DO NOT USE THIS PRODUCT! Even if you can find an equivalent 2-pole, I would not trust it with anything over 50V. For less than twice the cost you can get a UL-listed product from a major, reputable, manufacturer. The ones I have found aren't "rotary" but does that really matter? Up for one pump, down for the other pump, off in the middle.

This is exactly where I was going to go after you answered the HP question. Unless you have a driving need for a rotary switch, go with a snap switch. They cost a fraction of what suitable rotary switches cost as they are mass market items, while rotary switches are industrial control units sold in much smaller quantities. If you really want a rotary switch and don't want to go broke, use one like what you linked paired with some industrial contactors. The cost will go from dozens of dollars to hundreds though.
